# CSS 2 divs in one line always 100% of surrounding div

Tags: css, html

i have the following problem:
I have two small div's inside a div (width: 80%) and i want both small div's (float: left) to fill up the hole 80% of the page (=100% of the other div).
But if i set width to 50% it always seems to be a little bit bigger then half of the 80%-div and i really dont know why this happens.
For sure i tried to set width to 40% - this looks good for a small screen (about 500px) but if i stretch the window i have a lot of space on the right side.

I also tried to set the left div to float:left and the other one to float: right but then the problem is that if the space between both is too small it jumps into the next row...

Any ideas for the problem? Or are there any settings i have forgotten...
I'm happy for any of your ideas.

```
<section id="mainSection">
        <div id="question">Question?</div>
        <section id="answerSection">
            <div id="answer1" class="class1">A1</div>
            <div id="answer2" class="class1">A2</div>
            <div id="answer3" class="class1">A3</div>
            <div id="answer4" class="class1">A4</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </section>
    </section>

#mainSection{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#answerSection{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.class1{
    border-radius:8px;
    background-color: #CEE8FF;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: Do they have any padding/margins applied?

Comment: Well, can you post the code you are using?

Comment: Added code to the question.

Comment: Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nsu7b/. Play with the css. With 50-50 if you add a single px to width, the box will pop out (add 1px border). Add any padding, and it will pop out. Here's the box model that explains it.http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't give it exact 50% because you have added margin to it . margin doesnt gets calculated as the width of the div no matter what . Eg :- if you have a div with width 400px and you have its margin say 5px then the total width of the div will become 410px (5px from left margin + 5px from right ).

For this reason you will have to decrease the width by 10px to make it exact 400px.Now your div width will be 390px and after adding up those margin widths the total will be 400px.

 Same is the case with % divs. (In you code if you make the `.class1` 50% your total div width will be 50% + your margin px .Hence those will not be truly 50%)

Actually the border and padding width of the div also gets added up to the div's width but if you use this code -- >

```
*{
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

on your css, its always safe because now at least the padding and the border won't add up to the div's width e.g : if your div width is 400px and you add border width of 5px and padding width of 5px to the div with the above code written in the css you div will remain 400px and the padding and border will take their width from the existing 400px .

This is not the case with margins . So no matter what, you will have to add up margin width to your div or else don't add the margin at all..

this is a demo please go through it ---> [JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2nNt6/1/)

And here is a very nice explanation about the same -- > http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Thx the information about the margin was really usefull!
Thx a lot

Comment: Also go through this link ->  http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ for more a detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you try to make it responsive.

This is only suggested based on the information you provided, please use a fiddle or

try the following:

CSS:

```
.small {
    width: 80%;
}
.column {
    width: 48%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}
.column-fit {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 0 important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="small">
    <div class="column">text</div>
    <div class="column column-fit">text</div>
</div>
```

you can see it here:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brobken/mT59k/)